Replacing single switch with dimmer switch
Single switch has a blue and a yellow wire attached with no ground wire attached nor in the box. The box has 2 white wires capped together, one black wire capped and one red wire capped.
Trying to replace with Lutron DVCL-153PR-WH dimmer switch which has a ground wire, one red wire, one black wire and one red/white striped wire.
Is the current wiring compatible with the new dimmer switch? Haven't found anything online to explain the current wiring set up.

The colours of the wires sound like wires in a conduit system instead of cables.  Some conduit works like a ground wire, so connecting the switch ground wire to the metal(?) box is the easy part.  What does the dimmer switch instructions say about the red/white wire?  The blue and yellow are your hot and switch hot wires for the light, so red and black on the dimmer.

A fast search seems to say(did not check that far) that this switch can be used as a three way also(the third red/white wire).

Instructions on dimmer say to cap red/striped wire. Does it matter which wire (blue or yellow) gets connected to red or black wire on dimmer?

I think it might on a dimmer.  The black should go on the always hot.  The instructions should say if it matters, some do not care.
